# Python 3 unittest: How to extract results of tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am using Python's (3.4.1) `unittest` module for my unit tests.

I load all my testing module files using imports and then run unittest.main():

```
import unittest
import testing_module1
import testing_module2
# [...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This works perfectly for me as it is simple and respect the command line arguments I use to control verbosity or which test(s) to run.

I want to continue to output the same information, but I would like to generate an XML file from the results. I tried xmlrunner (https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting/) but:

- it does not output as much info to stdout as the standard runner;
- it uses a specific format of the XML that doesn't suites me.

I would like to generate the XML (I don't mind doing it manually) with the format I need but with minimal change to how the tests are run.

What are my options?

1. I could write my own TestRunner but I don't want to re-write everything, I just want to add extra output to the actual runner with minimal code change.
2. I could inherit unittest.TextTestRunner but I fear that adding XML output to it would require re-writing every methods, loosing the advantage of inheritance in the first place.
3. I could try to extract the test results after the call to `unittest.main()` and parse it. The problem here is that `unittest.main()` seems to exit when it's done so any code after it is not executed.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing two new classes, inheriting from `unittest.TextTestResult` and `unittest.TextTestRunner`. That way, I could run main like that:

```
unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(...))
```

I overloaded `unittest.TextTestRunner`'s `__init__` and those from `unittest.TextTestResult`:

- `addSuccess()`
- `addError()`
- `addFailure()`
- `addSubTest()`

For example:

```
def addSuccess(self, test):
    super().addSuccess(test)
    [... store the test into list, dictionary, whatever... ]
```

Since these `add*()` functions are called with the actual test, I can store them in a global list and parse them at the end of my `XMLTestRunner.run()`:

```
def run(self, test):
    result = super().run(test)
    self.save_xml_report(result)
    return result
```

Note that these functions are normally defined in `/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/runner.py`.

**Warning note**: By using an actual object passed `unittest.main()`'s `testRunner` argument as shown, the command line arguments given when launching python are ignored. For example, increasing verbose level with `-v` argument is ignored. This is because the `TestProgram` class, defined in `/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py`, detects if `unittest.main()` was run with `testRunner` being a class or an object (see `runTests()` near the end of the file). If you give just a class like that:

```
unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner)
```

then command line arguments are parsed. But you pass an instantiated object (like I need), `runTests()` will just use it as is. I thus had to parse arguments myself in my `XMLTestRunner.__init__()`:

```
# Similar to what /usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py's TestProgram._getParentArgParser() does.
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbosity',
                    action='store_const', const=2, default=1,  # Add default=1, not present in _getParentArgParser()
                    help='Verbose output')
parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', dest='verbosity',
                    action='store_const', const=0,
                    help='Quiet output')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--failfast', dest='failfast',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Stop on first fail or error')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--catch', dest='catchbreak',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Catch ctrl-C and display results so far')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--buffer', dest='buffer',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Buffer stdout and stderr during tests')
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get some more information as to how you did the overrides? This is precisely the thing I need to figure out how to do, but I'm not sure exactly how to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean the `addSuccess()` and co.? It's simply inheritance; the child class' method will have precedence over the parent's one...

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you.  Capture the output of unittest, which goes to sys.stderr, in a StringIO.  Continue after unittest.main by adding `exit=False'.  Read the captured output and process as you want.  Proof of concept:

```
import contextlib
import io
import sys
import unittest

class Mytest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def err_to(file):
    old_err = sys.stderr
    sys.stderr = file
    yield
    sys.stderr = old_err

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = io.StringIO()
    with err_to(result):
        unittest.main(exit=False)
    result.seek(0)
    print(result.read())
```

This prints (to sys.stdout)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Note: contextlib has redirect_stdout, but not redirect_stderr.  The above is simpler that the contextlib code.  The above assumes that there are no exceptions not caught by unittest.  See the contextlib.contextmanager doc for adding try:  except: finally.  I leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting path. But I need to store more information on a test than what appears on screen. And parsing might be quite tedious...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with catching FAIL events from unittest lib. Following big_gie's answer, this code appeared:

File `testFileName_1.py`

```
import unittest

class TestClassToTestSth(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_One(self):
        self.AssertEqual(True, False, 'Hello world')
```

```
import unittest
from io import StringIO
import testFileName_1

def suites():
    return [
        # your testCase classes, for example
        testFileName_1.TestClassToTestSth,
        testFileName_445.TestClassToTestSomethingElse,
    ]

class TextTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slack = Slack('data-engineering-tests')

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        super().addFailure(test, err)

        # Whatever you want here
        print(err, test)
        print(self.failures)


class TextTestRunner(unittest.TextTestRunner):
    resultclass = TextTestResult
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

stream = StringIO()
for test_case in suites():
    suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_case))
runner = TextTestRunner(stream=stream)
result = runner.run(suite)

stream.seek(0)
print(stream.read())
```